# port 27017 in use when port forwarding to aws documentDb instance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I am trying to connect my local nodejs application to my documentDb instance sitting on an ec2... I followed this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html

I couldnt get it to work, so I thought I may need to port forward, so I followed this guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect-from-outside-a-vpc.html

I try to connect... and I got port 27017 in use. Is this on my local pc or on the ec2? I killed port27017 on my pc, and still got the issue. If I kill port 27017 on my db instance won't my db stop? Or is that port 27017 on my empty ec2 instance I am trying to forward to?

Sorry if this is confusing, I myself am confused.

Comment: If you follow those commands, you're forwarding port 27017 from your local PC to the database's port 27017, so that you can configure your local database browser to connect to localhost, and SSH will forward the connection to the EC2 instance on to the database.

Comment: @AnonCoward ok so in which instance is the port already used? Thank you

Comment: It's already in use on the DocumentDB instance, when you run the SSH command, it's being used on your local machine.

Comment: @AnonCoward So to fix my issue.... where do I need to change port number? (sorry if misunderstood)

Comment: I don't know, what specific error, from which program are you seeing?

Comment: @AnonCoward I run a command like this ``` ssh -i "ec2Access.pem" -L 27017:sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 ubuntu@ec2-34-229-221-164.compute-1.amazonaws.com -N ```  and it says 27017 already in use

Comment: This '-L 27017' is the local port on your computer that you forward to 'sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017'. You may already have something listening on port 27017, maybe a mongodb instance. Try changing to something like '-L 37017'. Also, when connecting like this to DocumentDB, you'll not be able to connect in replica set mode, drop the '&replicaSet=rs0' from the URI. And disable TLS certificate verification, since you are, essentially, connecting to localhost.